# Javascript window.onmouseout or window.onMouseLeave not working

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to close the window when mouse moves out of window boundary.

I have a parent window and I am creating a new child window using `window.showModelessDialog`

I want to close this child window (`window.showModelessDialog`) when mouse moves out of the child window.

I have tried my luck with `window.onMouseLeave`, `window.onmouseout` but it doesn't fires up.

When I attached `mouseout` with document it worked but I want to cover window boundary.

Any help on this will be very helpful

Comment: See if it can helps you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923299/how-can-i-detect-when-the-mouse-leaves-the-window

Answer (score 1):

The *window* object does not support this event.

See: http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/window.shtml