# How do you capture mouseout on window?

Tags: javascript

**QUESTION DOES NOT ALREADY HAVE AN ANSWER** (if you can provide code that works instead of googling my question and linking to whatever answer comes up for the sweet sweet internet points then I will accept it as an answer. But since I have already been to all of those questions don't pretend like they work unless you can provide actual code that you have tested)

If you just do

```
$(window).on("mouseout", function() { alert("OUT"); });
```

you can mouseout on the left or right side of the window and it doesn't fire the event. I made a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ev0qx6up/) but it actually works fine because there is a border around the iframe.

So what is the best way to know if a mouse has left the window? I can put a 1px border around the page (composed of 4 divs). I can monitor x/y and tell if the mouse is on an edge. But ideally $(window).on("mouseout", foo) would tell me when the mouse has left the window.

Comment: You can use a transparent border with `box-sizing:border-box;`

Comment: JQuery mouseleave also works, but I can't remember too much; I'll look into jquery mouseleave.

Comment: Take a look at this; http://stackoverflow.com/a/8873586/3011082

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if the mouse exited the browser window using javascript/jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873508/how-can-i-check-if-the-mouse-exited-the-browser-window-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: I copied and pasted your code here and it worked. I am using Firefox 41, jquery.min.js 2.1.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3187524/2831645

Using jQuery you can rewrite the code like this:

```
$(window).on("mouseout", function(e) {
    if(!e.relatedTarget || e.relatedTarget.nodeName == 'HTML') {
        alert('left window');
    }
});
```

The code has been tested on latests Firefox & Chrome.

Comment: you da man! That works for me on both vertical and horizontal mouse outs.