# hiding a moving div when mouse if offscreen ( want not just to track when the mouse is offscreen)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code in js:

```
        window.onload = function(){
            var bsDiv = document.getElementById("box");
            var x, y;
// On mousemove use event.clientX and event.clientY to set the location of the div to the location of the cursor:
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
                x = event.clientX;
                y = event.clientY;                    
                if ( typeof x !== 'undefined' ){
                    bsDiv.style.left = x + "px";
                    bsDiv.style.top = y + "px";
                }
            }, false);
        }
    </script>
```

i want to add a function that if the cursor is off screen (or at position null?) it makes the element invisible and then make it re-visible on the cursors re entry

Comment: Generally the `mousemove` event doesn't fire when the mouse is off the screen

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873508/how-can-i-check-if-the-mouse-exited-the-browser-window-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: Posted jQuery answer [over there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40119133/1127972)

Answer (score 0):

`document.onmouseout` is triggered when the mouse leaves the screen.

so do something like

```
function invisible(div){
    div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
document.addEventListener(onmouseout, invisible(divName), true);
```

Comment: Did you try it? It does not work. It also bubbles so all `mouseout` will make it think it is outside the window.