# How to prevent document mouseout event from being triggered when the mouse enters an iframe?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, dom-events

I'm detecting if the mouse leaves the window as specified in this answer: [How can I detect when the mouse leaves the window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923299/how-can-i-detect-when-the-mouse-leaves-the-window).

The problem is that the browser triggers this event when the mouse enters an iframe (an embedded Youtube video in my case).

How can I prevent that?

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think you can directly you will have to apply some sort of hack or workaround. By definition an iframe is a different window... let me think on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to modify the handler this way:

```
addEvent(document, "mouseout", function(e) {
    e = e ? e : window.event;
    var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;

    // we will check if this won't be iframe
    var to = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if ((!from || from.nodeName == "HTML")
      && to.nodeName !== "IFRAME") {
        console.log('mouse out')
    }
});
```

**EDIT** Added `e.srcElement` option to support IE

Comment: Do you know if this solution is cross-browser?

Comment: This works mostly (in Firefox at least). But there still seems to be some false positive when the mouse goes fast over the iframe and back in the document.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but I am quite sure that `e.srcElement` will be IE compatible. I've edited the post. And with fast mouse move, it doesn't trigger anything for me, how did you do that?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why it does that, I have two iframes embeded (one in each other, the youtube video is in the second one). When the event is triggered the `from` var is `undefined` and the `to` var points to the background image of the body. But it's not really important since it is triggered really rarely.