# Detect when the mouse leaves the top of the viewport?

Tags: viewport, mouseleave

I want to detect when the mouse leaves the viewport on top (to the north so to say). I searched the net and came up with [How can I detect when the mouse leaves the window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923299/how-can-i-detect-when-the-mouse-leaves-the-window). Is a good start, but it also detects when the mouse leaves to other directions. How could I only detect the exit on top?

Thanks!

Comment: Track the position and put a guard on the last known position after detecting that the mouse left the window.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Would you explain a bit more pls?

Comment: Figured it out myself, thanks!

Comment: You'll need to tell us which language and platform you're using if you want a useful answer.  Please edit the tags of the question with that information.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

In order to detect mouseleave without taking in account the scroll bar and the autcomplete field :

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event){

  if(event.clientY <= 0 || event.clientX <= 0 || (event.clientX >= window.innerWidth || event.clientY >= window.innerHeight))
  {
     console.log("I'm out");
  }
});
```

Then you just have to delete conditions :

```
event.clientY <= 0  is when the mouse leave from the top
event.clientX <= 0  is when the mouse leave from the left
event.clientX >= window.innerWidth is when the mouse leave from the right
event.clientY >= window.innerHeight is when the mouse leave from the bottom
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this plugin: https://github.com/carlsednaoui/ouibounce

It fires an event when the mouse moves out of the top viewport.

[image]