# Overlay pop-ups on navigating nearby the closing tab and not on clicking the closing button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working  on designing a website for my academic project,in which the user has to fill some form. Now,the thing i want is whenever user tries to navigate nearby the closing tab (And not when he/she want to close it) or tires to enter the URL for some other website with being on the FILL-UP form page, user gets a pop-up (Which i have already designed using the overlay).Please note that i don't want to show the pop-up when user clicks the close button,Which i suppose can be  easily done with Window.Close() or onbeforeunload() function of the javascript.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The best way is probably tracking if the user gets his cursor out of the page.

Comment: Web pages should leave my f***ing browser controls alone :p

Comment: That's why i  don't want them to get irritated by asking the that leave the page confirmation.  I just want that overlay to just pop and nothing more.If user @JaromandaX  don't want to give it  a F*** he/she can choose to do so without any irritating messages.

Comment: sorry, it was a tongue in cheek comment.

Comment: It's possible , i've seen some websites are using it @JoelAlmeida . Yes your  solution can  be a possible solution but  how to track that thing whether the cursor is out of window or not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923299/how-can-i-detect-when-the-mouse-leaves-the-window#answer-3187524