# Javascript pageY issue with Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-edge, pagey

I want to create a simple script that will detect if user mouse leave window. Solution is already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3187524/1207443) by using mouseout event. The problem with this solution is that it will trigger action also if user goes with mouse to scroller. So I added extra if condition `e.pageY < jQuery(window).scrollTop()` to this code:

```
addEvent(document, "mouseout", function(e) {
    e = e ? e : window.event;
    var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
    if ((!from || from.nodeName == "HTML") && e.pageY < jQuery(window).scrollTop()) {
        alert("left window");
    }
});
```

It works fine in all browsers, excepting Microsoft Edge. In Edge e.pageY won't be necessary 0 or -1,-2... as in other browsers but it will be 50,34,... (depends how fast you move mouse).

I am wondering if there is any simple solution to this problem.

Comment: I just realized that even some biggest exit intend services have the same problem, it seems it is indeed Edge problem and not so easy to solve it.